# Assert.IsTrue failed exception when running unit test. (c# and visual studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

The following unit tests are designed to pass, however the following exception occurs:

```
Assert.IsTrue failed.
```

[image]

Does this imply that the Assert.IsTrue method is not evening getting called?
What changes need to be made to get the unit test to pass correctly? I've added a reference to the main program that is being unit tested.
The unit test reads from the test url link stored in var content and runs regular expression to match the elements with the url link.

Here is the unit test code:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using SimpleWebScraper.Builders;
using SimpleWebScraper.Data;
using SimpleWebScraper.Workers;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace SimpleWebScraper.Test.Unit
{
    [TestClass]

    public class ScraperTest
    {

        private readonly Scraper _scraper = new Scraper();
        [TestMethod]
        public void FindCollectionWithNoParts()
        {
            var content = "Some fluff data <a href=\"http://example.com\" data-id=\"someId\" class=\"result-title hdrlnk\">some text</a> more fluff data";
            
            ScrapeCriteria scrapeCriteria = new ScrapeCriteriaBuilder()
                .WithData(content)
                .WithRegex(@"<a href=\""(.*?)\"" data-id=\""(.*?)\"" class=\""result-title hdrlnk\"" id=\""(.*?)\"" >(.*?)</a>")
                .WithRegexOption(RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture)
                .Build();

            var foundElements = _scraper.Scrape(scrapeCriteria);

            Assert.IsTrue(foundElements.Count == 1);
            Assert.IsTrue(foundElements[0] == "<a href=\"http://example.com\" data-id=\"someId\" class=\"result-title hdrlnk\">some text</a>");
        }


        [TestMethod]
        public void FindCollectionWithTwoParts()
        {
            var content = "Some fluff data <a href=\"http://example.com\" data-id=\"someId\" class=\"result-title hdrlnk\">some text</a> more fluff data";
            ScrapeCriteria scrapeCriteria = new ScrapeCriteriaBuilder()
                       .WithData(content)
                       .WithRegex(@"<a href=\""(.*?)\"" data-id=\""(.*?)\"" class=\""result-title hdrlnk\"" id=\""(.*?)\"" >(.*?)</a>")
                        .WithRegexOption(RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture)
                        .WithPart(new ScrapeCriteriaPartBuilder()
                        .WithRegex(@">(.*?)</a>")
                        .WithRegexOption(RegexOptions.Singleline)
                        .Build())
                        .WithPart(new ScrapeCriteriaPartBuilder()
                        .WithRegex(@"href=\""(.*?)""")
                        .WithRegexOption(RegexOptions.Singleline)
                        .Build())
                        .Build();

            var foundElements = _scraper.Scrape(scrapeCriteria);

            Assert.IsTrue(foundElements.Count == 2);
            Assert.IsTrue(foundElements[0] == "some text");
            Assert.IsTrue(foundElements[1] == "http://example.com");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without understanding what your code is trying to do, one of your assertions is failing. Unfortunately, we don't know which from the information given. You should use the IsTrue(bool, string) override to include a helpful message when the assertion fails. For example: Assert.IsTrue(foundElements.Count == 2, "Count of elements was expected to be 2.")

Comment: (And to answer your question more directly - your assert IS being called, but the boolean that it's testing for is false)

Comment: Instead of `Assert.IsTrue(foundElements.Count == 1);` you should write `Assert.Equal(1, foundElements.Count)`. This will print a more detailed message.